# Django App fails to upload file to quickbooks

Tags: python, django, quickbooks

Hello all I am encountering a problem while trying to upload a file to quickbooks using the api. Below is the code, I get a success but the file is not sent or cannot be found in the bill itself. Any help would be appreciated.

```
Inside my app views.py

def handle_file_uploads(request):
    auth_client = AuthClient(
        settings.CLIENT_ID,
        settings.CLIENT_SECRET,
        settings.REDIRECT_URI,
        settings.ENVIRONMENT,
        access_token=request.session.get('access_token', None),
        refresh_token=request.session.get('refresh_token', None),
        realm_id=request.session.get('realm_id', None),
    )

    if auth_client.access_token is None:
        return JsonResponse({'status': 'failure', 'message': 'Access token not available.'})

    if auth_client.realm_id is None:
        raise ValueError('Realm id not specified.')

    if request.method == 'POST':
        # Get the file input names for each bill ID
        bill_ids = [key.replace('bill_', '') for key in request.FILES.keys()]

        for bill_id in bill_ids:
            uploaded_file = request.FILES.get(f'bill_{bill_id}')

            if uploaded_file:
                # Prepare the API endpoint URL to upload the attachment
                url = f"https://sandbox-quickbooks.api.intuit.com/v3/company/{auth_client.realm_id}/upload"
                
                # Prepare the request headers
                headers = {
                    'Authorization': f'Bearer {auth_client.access_token}',
                }
                
                # Prepare the file data to be sent as multipart form data
                files = {
                    'file_content': (uploaded_file.name, uploaded_file.read(), uploaded_file.content_type),
                }

                # Make the API call to upload the attachment
                response = requests.post(url, files=files, headers=headers)
                print(response.json)
                # Check the response status and handle the error case if necessary
                if response.status_code != 200:
                    error_message = 'API call failed with status code: {}'.format(response.status_code)
                    response_content = response.text  # Get the response content
                    return JsonResponse({'status': 'error', 'message': error_message, 'response_content': response_content})

        return JsonResponse({'status': 'success'})

    # Return a JSON response indicating failure if the request method is not POST or data is missing
    return JsonResponse({'status': 'failure', 'message': 'Invalid request'})

the html

<div class="table-container">
  <form action="{% url 'app:handle_file_uploads' %}" method="post" id="upload-form" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <table id="bill-table">
      <tr>
        <th>Bill ID</th>
        <th>Vendor Name</th>
        <th>Invoice Type</th>
        <th>Date</th>
        <th>Amount</th>
        <th>Attached PDF Name</th>
        <th>Attach File</th>
        <!-- Added column for browse button -->
      </tr>
      {% for bill in bill_details %}
      <tr>
        <td name="billID">{{ bill.Id }}</td>
        <td>{{ bill.VendorRef.name }}</td>
        <td>Bill</td>
        <td>{{ bill.TxnDate }}</td>
        <td>{{ bill.TotalAmt }}</td>
        <td>{{ bill.AttachmentFile }}</td>
        <td>
          {% if bill.AttachmentFile == "NoFileUploaded" %}
          <input
            type="file"
            class="attach-file-input"
            name="bill_{{ bill.Id }}"
            accept=".pdf"
          />
          {% endif %}
        </td>
      </tr>
      {% endfor %}
    </table>
    <button type="submit">Upload</button>
  </form>
</div>
```

I tried the above code and a few other things but I used to get an error now still getting a success response but nothing else.